# How to create a transformation matrix to reorient 3d objects

Tags: linear-algebra

I am a computer scientist trying to reimplement a physics simulator described [here](https://www.liebertpub.com/doi/abs/10.1089/soro.2013.0010).

In the paper there is a lattice of voxels (left), that is modeled as a  lattice of points connected by elastic beams (right).

[image: Voxel Lattice]

Given a pair of voxels $(vx_1, vx_2)$ with positions and rotations $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$, $(\theta_{x_1}, \theta_{y_1}, \theta_{z_1}$), $(x_2, y_2, z_2)$, $(\theta_{x_2}, \theta_{y_2}, \theta_{z_2}$)

I need to rotate/translate them via a matrix $m$, (or possibles a quaternion) such that the positions and angles of the first voxel are zero and the beam connecting them is oriented only in the positive $x$-direction.

If what I am asking doesn't make sense the relevant pages from the paper can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rUxOqg-XWlfhF1Ek5i6uLrf8A7HBdAQV).

Comment: You might want to ask this at SE.Math, SE.ComputerScience, or SE.ComputerGraphics instead.

Comment: Not clear. This seems to be a mathematical exercise concerning translation and rotation matrices, not a physics problem. If the position of voxel 1 is (x,y,z) then applying the operation -(x,y,z) to all points in space will move it to the origin. Likewise for its orientation. But I don't see how this would give you any freedom to alter the orientation of the beam joining the two voxels. If the beam is bent as in the diagram I don't see how it can be oriented in a single direction.

Comment: As far as I understand (I'm no physicist) what I want is a passive transformation or really transforming the reference frame. I guess I may have worded that part poorly since the beam could be bent, but by being oriented in the positive x direction I guess I mean that the beam exits from vx1 in that direction.